# Why Third printf will print undefined value?

Tags: c, pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        int *p = &i;
        foo(&p);
        printf("%d ", *p);
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }
    void foo(int **const p)
    {
      int j = 11;
        *p = &j;
        printf("%d ", **p);
    }
```

What wii be the final output
Why Third printf will print undefined value ?

Comment: all the three printf's are printing 11. What's your expected output.?

Comment: For which standard of C ? C99 or something earlier ?

Comment: What undefined value? They all print 11

Comment: The problem is that `foo` assignes to the main p an address of a local variable j. Following the C standard the value of `j` and hence `*p` is undefined after leaving `foo`.

Comment: @Marian: That's an *answer*, not a comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Within `foo`, you assign a value to `*p` which points to a location on the stack that's been allocated to `foo`. When `foo` returns, the stack is popped, and that location is free for reuse — but the `p` in `main` still points to it.

When you call `printf` in `main` the first time, it happens that that that location on the stack hasn't (yet) had any new data written to it, and so reading `*p` gives you `11`, and you push that on the stack along with some other things for the call to `printf`, and it succeeds in printing `11`. But the action of calling `printf` changes the data on the stack, including (potentially) the location that `p` (in `main`) points to, because the stack was popped after `foo` returned.

The *second* call then uses the data from that stack location again, which may have been changed by the first call to `printf`.

Moral of the story: Don't keep pointers to stack locations that have been popped.

Answer (score 0):

Third `printf` is printing the right value.  The problem is that `j` is an automatic local variable and it is no longer exist once function return.  Therefore, `p` in `main` is not pointing to the place you are expecting and ultimately your program invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Possible solutions:
1. Use `static` keyword in the declaration of `j`

```
void foo(int **const p)
{
    static int j = 11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

2. Dynamically allocate `j`

```
void foo(int **const p)
{
    int *j = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *j = 11;
    *p = j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the "i" in foo is stack-allocated, every thing will work fine until it goes off from the memory, so printf of foo will work fine,while the second printf and the third printf will work until the integer i of foo goes off from the memory. This is a system issue, it has the probability that the 2 last printf's work or don't work. If you wanna them work all the time you need to heap-allocate integer i of foo using mallo

Answer (score 0):

When **void foo()** is called ,new stack frame gets created on stack so **int j = 11;** being a local variable goes into this stack frame . So say int j is at address 0x000ffd with value 10  so your *p now stores this address . Now  what happens when this function returns **stack unwinds**

During Stack Unwinding , it does all the work of cleanup. so all data which is into that stack frame  gets destroyed so now that address **0x000ffd might have same value or something different** but variable j is not associated to it now.  So its undefined behavior